# Concurrent process execution order

Tags: concurrency, process, erlang

Trying to figure out how Erlang concurrency works. For testing, I have the following modules:

server.erl:

```
-module(server).
-export([loop/0]).


loop() ->

    receive

        {foo, Msg_foo} ->
            io:format("~w~n", [Msg_foo]),
            loop();

        {bar, Msg_bar} ->
            io:format("~w~n", [Msg_bar]),
            loop();

        stop -> 
            io:format("~s~n", ["End server process"]),
            true

    end.
```

process_a.erl

```
-module(process_a).
-export([go_a/0]).

go_a() ->

    receive

        {foo, Pid1} ->
            Pid1 ! {foo, 'Message foo from process A'},
            go_a();

        {bar, Pid2} ->
            Pid2 ! {bar, 'Message bar from process A'},
            go_a()

    end.
```

process_b.erl

```
-module(process_b).
-export([go_b/0]).

go_b() ->

    receive

        {foo, Pid1} ->
            Pid1 ! {foo, 'Message foo from process B'},
            go_b();

        {bar, Pid2} ->
            Pid2 ! {bar, 'Message bar from process B'},
            go_b()

    end.
```

client.erl

```
-module(client).
-export([start/0]).
-import(server, [loop/0]).
-import(process_a, [go_a/0]).
-import(process_b, [go_b/0]).


go() ->

    Server_Pid = spawn(server, loop, []),

    Pid_A = spawn(process_a, go_a, []),
    Pid_B = spawn(process_b, go_b, []),

    Pid_A ! {foo, Server_Pid},
    Pid_B ! {bar, Server_Pid},

    Pid_A ! {bar, Server_Pid},
    Pid_B ! {foo, Server_Pid},

    Pid_A ! {foo, Server_Pid},
    Pid_B ! {foo, Server_Pid},

    Pid_A ! {bar, Server_Pid},
    Pid_B ! {bar, Server_Pid}.


start() ->
    go().
```

The client sends messages to process A and process B which in turn send messages to the server. The order of the messages is:

```
A foo
B bar
A bar
B foo
A foo
B foo
A bar
B bar
```

but the program output is:

```
'Message foo from process A'
'Message bar from process A'
'Message foo from process A'
'Message bar from process A'
'Message bar from process B'
'Message foo from process B'
'Message foo from process B'
'Message bar from process B'
```

The server first processes all messages from process A, then all the messages from process B. My question is, what does determine the message processing order? I thought that it was the order in which the messages were received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on process scheduling. After your client code starts the server and procs A and B, those processes are newly created but might not even have been given any time to execute yet (and if they have, they will immediately be suspended in their receives). The client code keeps executing and quickly sends off a bunch of messages to A and B. These are asynchronous operations and the client process will not have to suspend at all before returning from the call to go().

As soon as a suspended process gets a message, it becomes ready to be scheduled for execution, but it can take a fraction of time before this happens. Meanwhile, more messages may keep arriving in their mailboxes, so when A or B actually start running, they are likely to have all four messages from the client already in their mailboxes. In general you can also not be sure which of A and B will start to execute first, even though the scheduling probably is very predictable in a simple case like this.

So in your case, A gets scheduled before B, it starts executing, and in very short time it consumes all its messages. This does not take much work, so A won't even spend a whole time slice. Then it suspends due to its mailbox being empty. Then B gets scheduled and does the same thing.

If there had been many processes, and/or a lot of work, the Erlang VM could have split the processes up across schedulers on different OS threads (running in truly parallel fashion if you have a multicore CPU). But since the example is so simple, these processes are probably handled within a single scheduler, and thus the ordering becomes even more predictable. If both A and B had thousands of messages in their queue, or each message took a lot of computational effort to process, you would see the messages getting interleaved.

(By the way, your import declarations in the client do nothing, since you are using spawn(Module, Fname, Args). If you had written e.g. spawn(fun() -> loop() end) they would be needed.)